# Getting Popular posts

Tags: php, mysql

tables:
POSTS
    (id
    title
    data
    userid)

CONNECTIONS(
    postid
    userid)

I want to get rows from the POSTS table by the amount of c.postid values that are the same in the CONENCTIONS c table

In easier terms, I want to get the most popular posts, with the most connections.

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: How many do you want to see? Because you can see the 10 most popular or the 100000000000 most popular.

Comment: I have a variable that has the amount to show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, c.cnt from posts p INNER JOIN (
    SELECT postid, count(*) as cnt 
    FROM connections 
    GROUP BY postid ORDER BY cnt DESC /*limit goes here if you need it!*/) c 
ON c.postid = p.id
```

A little warning:

It would be pretty heavy query in case if you dealing with high loads. I'd suggest to have the `cnt` (a number of connections) field right within your `posts` table (it would be a denormalization and it's harder to maintain, but would work good enough to decrease querying time by 2 times or more if you would create an `index` on `cnt` field).

Let me know if the query has worked or not, cause I can't check myself right now.

Comment: Yeah works great! I had to change the `GROUP BY postid DESC` to `GROUP BY postid ASC` Other than that, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Well to get the max value from the `connections` table, try this:

`SELECT MAX(postid) FROM userid`

Not quite sure about the rest, but that will give you the highest value of `postid` in the table `userid`.

Comment: I don't want the highest value, I want values that are the same in other rows.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM posts,connections WHERE posts.userid=connections.userid`

Answer (score 0):

Replace the 50 with the number of popular posts that you want to get:

```
select * from post where postid in (
select postid from (
select count(*),postid from connections group by postid order by count(*) desc limit 50 ))
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it, but try something like this.
It will join posts to connections in order of the most connections.
(you can adjust the limit depending on your requirements)

```
select posts.id, posts.title, posts.data, posts.userid, COUNT(connections.postid) AS total
from posts join connections on posts.id=connections.postid
order by total desc
limit 20
```